# Data alignment in plotting bar chart from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot 2 axes in a bar chart using 2 different dictionaries, that has exactly the same keys, using matplotlib.
I wasn't able to make sure that the items (keys and values) of the two dictionaries are in the same order.

code example:

```
ind = numpy.arange(len(types_dict))  # the x locations for the groups
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, types_dict.values(), 0.35, color='green')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+0.35, genome_types_dict.values(), 0.35, color='purple')
plt.xticks(ind+width, types_dict.keys(), fontsize=10)
plt.savefig(output+"bar_" + library_name + ".png")
```

When printing the keys for the dictionaries types_dict and genome_types_dict, their keys are not in order, and therefore also their values:

```
types_dict = ['rRNA', 'IGR', '3UTR', 'sRNA', 'tRNA', 'TU', '5UTR', 'AS', 'cis_AS_with_trans_t', 'mRNA', 'other-ncRNA']
genome_types_dict = ['rRNA', 'IGR', '3UTR', '5UTR', 'tRNA', 'TU', 'sRNA', 'AS', 'cis_AS_with_trans_t', 'mRNA', 'other-ncRNA']
```

Looking for a solution for the alignment between the 2 dictionaries.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining lists rather than dictionaries because you're using square brackets. If you want dictionaries, you'll need to wrap your data in {}. In Python, list order is preserved, dict order is not, unless you use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Further, the elements in the two lists you've defined are strings (they're defined in quotes), which you're attempting to plot on the y-axis against against your x-axis (ind) values. You'll need *numerical data* to plot against ind.

Presumably you'd like to define true dictionary key-values pairs with numerical value data, such as:

```
genome_dict = {'rRNA': 1, 'IGR': 2, '3UTR': 3, '5UTR': 4, 'tRNA': 6, 'TU': 7, 'sRNA': 8, 'AS': 9, 'cis_AS_with_trans_t': 10, 'mRNA': 11, 'other-ncRNA': 12}
```

Using that, you can extract the keys and use them as your graph axis labels with ax.set_xticklabels. You can use the dictionary's values as the second argument in your rects = ax.bar() expression, i.e. as the y-axis values, and thus produce a plot of numerical data against ind, with each bar labelled as a genome type.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using OrderedDict